# Flutter semi circle curve shape of slider

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-slider

How to create track of slider as semi circle curve along with custom thumb, Please refer to image

[image]

till now what I have created is below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) package.
Its appearance customization will meet your needs.

[image]